# Стандартное содержимое файла при создании класса в IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Здравствуйте! Я использую IDE intellij-idea для решения оллимпиадных задач. 
Каждое решение храню в отдельном проекте.
Так вот при создании класса стандартное содержимое файла:

```
/**
* Created by Work on 06.03.2015.
 */

public class Ex {
}
```

И постоянно приходится прописывать

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
}
```

Можно ли как-нибудь изменить содержимое файла при создании класса?

Comment: protip: наберите в окне редактора `psvm` и нажмите `<TAB>`.

Comment: @Nofate ♦ про psvm не знал. Очень удобно.

Comment: @Gaponec, загляните в `Settings->Live Templates`, там много разного.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вас так утомляет написание этих строк, зайдите в Главном меню в `File->Settings->Editor->Templates->File and Code Templates` и отредактируйте шаблон класса на свой вкус.

Comment: Когда каждый день пишешь эти строки по 10-20 раз, то такой вопрос начинает интересовать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

preferences -> file and code templates